# how to efficiently reuse mysql queries that are called from an api

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, query-optimization, api-design

I am making a website and have a series of sql statements that are used over and over. I'm wondering if there's any way to optimize this process (in terms of performance) using views, procedures, or something else that I don't know about. The backend works like so:

1. The frontend make a request to `www.api.com/{page}/{user}` for the page and user that it needs data for
2. The backend receives the request and executes a pre-written prepared sql statement, simply passing in the user's name (each page returns the same amount/type of data, the only difference is what user's data we need to get)
3. The backend converts the result into json and passes it to the frontend

The mysql query ends up looking like `SELECT * FROM ... WHERE user = :user` for each page. Because it's essentially the same query being run over and over, is there any way to optimize this for performance using the various features of MySQL?

Comment: Is it causing a performance bottleneck to run those queries?

Answer (score 1):

Views are syntactic sugar -- no performance gain.

Stored procedures are handy when you can bundle several things together.  However, you can do similar stuff with an application subroutine.  One difference is that the SP is all performed on the server, thereby possibly avoiding some network lag between the client and server.

Within an SP, there is `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE`.  This provides only a small performance improvement.

The best help (in your one example) is to have `INDEX(user)` on that table.

Will you be performing a query more than a thousand times a second?  If so, we need to dig deeper into more of the moving parts of the app.

"Premature optimization" comes to mind *for the simple example given*.